# How to select values from a data frame without the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-loc

I set the first column ("time") in my data frame as the index. Then I used loc and iloc to choose the three specific columns(x,y,z) that I need. But it contains "time" as well. What should I do to get the values from three specific columns without the index,"time"?   In the picture, I only want

-302.13
   -303.13
   -302.69
   -303.03
   -302.55
   -302.60
   -302.46
   -302.59.

[image]

```
marker_thirteen = coda3.loc[[8.1, 11.7, 13.475, 14.855, 15.125, 17.465, 19.82, 22.5],['13:-.X', '13:-.Y', '13:-.Z']]
original_x = marker_thirteen.iloc[:, 0]
print (marker_thirteen)
print(original_x)
```

Comment: can't you create a new df containing the columns you need with reset_index()?

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this:

```
original_x = marker_thirteen.drop(['13:-.Y', '13:-.Z'], axis=1)

print(list(original_x['13:-.X']))
```

Comment: ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Sorry about that. I just modified my original comment. Try that and let me know

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code but it says "NameError: name 'coda3' is not defined" Can you write down as well the code that extracted coda3?

Comment: I just modified the code again. Please let me know if it works. Again without the original data, I can only do much, but yeah let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank you, but it says "'list' object is not callable".

Comment: I see. Without the data from coda3 there is not really much I can do unfortunately.

Comment: Great! I’m glad I could help